# Terminology: rate of growth of $y$ when $y = \sqrt{x}$

Tags: terminology

If

- $y = x^2$, then $y$ grows quadraticaly with $x$,
- $y = \log x$, then $y$ grows logarithmicaly with $x$.

How does $y$ depend on $x$ if $y = \sqrt{x}$?

Comment: It grows as the square root.. There is no particular name for that rate of growth.

Comment: I'd say that $y$ grows as the square root ***of*** $x$.

Comment: Can one of you two post this as an answer, please?

Comment: The $x$ grows quadratic-ally with $y$.

Comment: @SimpleArt I was aware of this "solution", but if $y$ is the dependent variable, this answer does not make much sanse ...

Comment: Sure it does, because $x$ could be the dependent variable of $y$.  :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the first comments by Ethan Bolker and Lovsovs suggest, the answer is that

> $y$ grows as the square root of $x$.